# Java TCP client/server interaction

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

Hi so I have a program that is used to exchange messages from client to server and back through TCP. The messages come from a command line argument that is a file. The file will always have at least one integer per line and there is always a space between each integer.

Here's a sample file:

```
7 3 21 
23 2 8
3
```

Each line is considered to be a message so the above example has 3 messages total.

What my program does is the client sends a message(a line of integers) to the server and the server sends a message back containing the largest prime integer below each number (if the number is prime it does nothing and returns that number). This works for my program. My problem is that after each line is sent the client must wait for a response from the server before it sends another message(i.e another line from the file). I have not been able to find a solution of how to do this and frankly I'm not sure how I would tell if my program was doing this or not(I'm using eclipse). I suspect mines not doing it because my output is being printed all on the same line instead of it being on separate lines like the text file. Here's what I mean.

Sample file:

```
8 3 21
5 2 31 3
```

My output:

```
7 3 19 5 2 31 3
```

Expected output:

```
7 3 19
5 2 31 3
```

As you can see everything works up until another line is sent.

Here's code from my 3 classes:

```
public class TCPClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        try{ 
            int port = (new Integer(args[1])).intValue();
            Socket mySock = new Socket(args[0], port);
            Scanner in = new Scanner(
                    new InputStreamReader(mySock.getInputStream()));
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream( mySock.getOutputStream());
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(args[2]));

            while(scan.hasNextLine()){
                String msg = scan.nextLine();
                out.println(msg);

            }

            while(in.hasNextLine()){    
            System.out.println(in.nextLine());
            }

            mySock.close();

        }catch (Exception e){
        }
    }
}
```

More code:

```
public class TCPServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int port = (new Integer(args[0])).intValue();
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(port);

        while(true){
            Socket connection = socket.accept();

            PrimeFunction request = new PrimeFunction(connection);

            Thread thread = new Thread(request);

            thread.start();

        }
    }
}
```

Last bit of code:

```
final class PrimeFunction implements Runnable {
    Socket socket;

    public PrimeFunction (Socket socket) throws Exception{
        this.socket = socket;

    }

    public void run() {
        try{
            processRequest();
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    private void processRequest() throws Exception {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        while(in.hasNextLine()){
            String[] arr = in.nextLine().split(" ");
            int[] intarr = new int[arr.length];

            for(int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++){
                intarr[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);

                if (prim(intarr[i]) == true){
                    out.println(intarr[i] + " ");

                }else{

                    while (!prim(--intarr[i])){
                    }
                    out.println(intarr[i] + " ");
                }
            }           



        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
        socket.close();
    }

    public static boolean prim(int m){
        int n = m;
        for(int i = 2; i< n/2; i++){
            if(n % i == 0){
                return false;
            }
        }   
        return true;
    }


}
```

Final thoughts: I'm unsure of how to tell if my client waits for a response before it sends another message.

Updated PrimeFunction class and it now prints in the correct format. However, still don't know if it the client is waiting.

New code (added String output in ProcessRequest):

```
final class PrimeFunction implements Runnable {
    Socket socket;

    public PrimeFunction (Socket socket) throws Exception{
        this.socket = socket;

    }

    public void run() {
        try{
            processRequest();
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    private void processRequest() throws Exception {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        while(in.hasNextLine()){
            String[] arr = in.nextLine().split(" ");
            int[] intarr = new int[arr.length];
            String output = "";

            for(int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++){
                intarr[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);

                if (prim(intarr[i]) == true){
                    output += intarr[i] + " ";
                    //out.println(intarr[i] + " ");

                }else{

                    while (!prim(--intarr[i])){
                    }
                    output += intarr[i] + " ";
                    //out.println(intarr[i] + " ");
                }
            }           

            out.println(output);
            output = "";

        }

        in.close();
        out.close();
        socket.close();
    }

    public static boolean prim(int m){
        int n = m;
        for(int i = 2; i < n / 2; i++){
            if(n % i == 0){
                return false;
            }
        }   
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: You don't need to test up to n to determine if something is prime

Comment: Ya n/2 would be much better thanks for pointing out

Comment: actually its sqrt(n)

Comment: Just add a println("") after the for loop

Comment: I fixed it to get the correct format a different way but that still doesn't help me with knowing if the client waits for the server to send something back before it sends another line. Do you have any other ideas? Or maybe it is waiting, I honestly don't know because I'm clueless on how to test for such a thing.

Comment: You need to read *one* line from the server for every line you read from the terminal and send to the server. Inside the `nextLine()` loop.

Comment: @EJP For it to be correctly formatted or is this how you would know if the client waits before it sends another line?

Comment: For the client to read the response from the server before it sends the next request. You want request/response/request/response, right? You haven't coded it that way. I don't understand this 'know if the client waits' business.

Comment: Yes that's how I want it. I'll try to explain it a different way. I don't understand what the output would look like in the console with the request/response/request/response that you described. For instance would it just print all the responses at once or would it print a response wait, print a response wait, print a response? How would I know that it physically waited?

Comment: It would read a line from the terminal, which would be echoed, send that as a request, get the response, print that response, read another line, ... The waits come while the user is typing, or out to lunch, and while the server is processing the request.

Comment: Okay thanks, that makes sense. I would then want to modify the nextLine() loop in my TCPClient class to initially read a line and then after that it would only read a line after it received output from the server.

Comment: No. You need to do what I said. Why *the hell* don't you just try it?

Comment: "You need to read one line from the server for every line you read from the terminal and send to the server. Inside the nextLine() loop". I have more than one nextLine() loop as you described and I thought the way to do was in the client class but I'm wrong.